# Django Unit Test- How to avoid rollback for each unit test case

Tags: django

I am new to Django framework. I am writing Django unit test cases. The DB transactions are getting roll-backed for each test case. Is it possible to avoid the rollback since I want to use that DB data for other test cases?

Comment: Can you add your current tests to your question? You would usually use [TestCase.setUpTestData](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TestCase.setUpTestData) to shared data between multiple tests in a TestCase

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setUp(self)` and `tearDown(self)` methods within a test class, which are run before and after (respectively) for class-wide initialization.

I.e. if you create an object in a test class's `setUp(self)` method, that object will be available to all tests within that class.

If you want to share a resource between test classes, then you should probably re-evaluate the problem you are trying to solve.

This is worth a read:
[Testing in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/tools/#example)

Comment: Why "re-evaluate"? Given a sufficiently complex application, there will inevitably be great benefit to having some reusable setups, on which multiple behaviors are tested in separate unittest methods.

Comment: If you tear down and recreate everything every time, large test suites will grow unbearably slow. Sure, some care needs to be taken - the persisted state may bite you if tests can mutate it without rolling back their mutations, then one test method may unexpectedly end up affecting the behavior of other methods.

Comment: Cannot edit but wanted to clarify that the same applies to reuse between classes.

Answer (score 0):

Methods `setUpClass`, and `setUpTestData`, are designed for that, they would not rollback between methods.

If you want keep the state you set up around even longer, between TestCase classes, then fixtures may help. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/fixtures/

(By saying "test case", you may have meant a test method or a TestCase class - people sometimes use the term vaguely, so take care)